# kdb/q -- how to number the rows by certain groupings

Tags: kdb

I have tables with `date;sym` columns. But each date might have multiple syms. I want to number the occurrences of symbol in each date

For example:

```
date        sym 
-------------------
2019.06.04  ABC
2019.06.04  DEF
2019.06.04  ABC
2019.06.05  DEF
2019.06.05  ABC
```

will give me

```
date        sym   c 
-------------------
2019.06.04  ABC   1
2019.06.04  DEF   1
2019.06.04  ABC   2   / here ABC appears for the second time on this date. 
2019.06.05  DEF   1
2019.06.05  ABC   1
```

Comment: Are you looking for date X sym count in one table or across multiple tables?

Comment: I don't know about kdb but I would create a procedure that when I insert into `table` the procedure would count the `distinct` dates and syms and adjust the values accordingly. I will leave the experts to provide the answers though. :P

Comment: @AntonDovzhenko just one table. not the count of symbols though. i want to number the symbol occurrences by dates.

Comment: @Vendetta. Thank you for explanation. 
I've created query which could solve your problem, though I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a little cleaner, here the c column is just a running sum of all rows that have been grouped by each combination of date and sym.

```
q)t:([]date:2019.06.04+0 0 0 1 1;sym:`ABC`DEF`ABC`DEF`ABC)

q)update c:sums i=i by date,sym from t

date       sym c
----------------
2019.06.04 ABC 1
2019.06.04 DEF 1
2019.06.04 ABC 2
2019.06.05 DEF 1
2019.06.05 ABC 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the occurrences of syms by date across all of the tables in a HDB we can run a count by date for each of the partitioned tabled `.Q.pt` and then scan that over `pj` plus join, as each table is keyed on date (matching keys). As `pj` is similar to an `ij` we need to ensure that there are no rows dropped as each date might be missing different syms

```
q)cntTabs:{2!0!update c:count each sym,sym:first each sym from select sym by date from x} each .Q.pt
q){t:pj[x;y];t,k!y k:key[y] except key[t]}/[cntTabs]
```